# XCode4 : Changing BundleID

Tags: iphone

I created an app which called say Foo in XCode.

When I decided to publish this app, I wanted to name the app FooApp instead of Foo. So, that is the bundleID that was created.

The problem now is that the bundle ID's in XCode vs. iTunesConnect do not match.

I tried to edit info.plist but it seems to mess up my project and it will no longer run at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was an anomaly. I was able to match the bundle ID on the portal to my plist.info. In my case, I needed to change the bundle ID in my project because I had created a bundle ID with a different name on the portal That worked.

Answer (score 0):

The BundleID should not be changed, it is the string that identifies your app to the App Store.

Rather than edit the 'Bundle identifier' you need to modify the 'PRODUCT_NAME' item in Build Settings and then type in ${PRODUCT_NAME} into the options 'Bundle Name' & 'Bundle Display Name' inside your info.plist

Comment: You can change the bundle id and it my case it was necessary. It just needs to match whatever you entered on the portal. And I did successfully change it in info.plist. I'm not sure why it screwed up my project the first time but all is good now.